# Singlish to Sinhala converting API

Tags: javascript, html, api, web, converter

I want to convert Singlish text to Sinhala in my webpage. Therefore I'm looking for a good API for it. I found one it is http://www.easysinhalaunicode.com/API.html but it converts some Singlish text in a wrong way. Do you know any which works better than above API?

Thanks in advance